# Java regex - allow only if n digits in group from long string

Tags: java, regex

i need a regex which allows a string, unless there are 6 or more numbers in a group at any point.

my current wrong regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z ]*)|(\d{0,5})$
```

match:

```
teststring 12345
teststring
1234 teststring
teststring 123 teststring
test1234string
```

not match:

```
1234567 teststring
teststring 123456
test123456789string
```

i hope someone can help.
thx guys

---

**UPDATE:**
this regex does the job:

```
^(?!.*\d{6}).*$
```

thx @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Maybe something like [`s.matches("(?!.*\\d{6}).*")`](https://regex101.com/r/sDxXVU/1) will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i think it better update as : ^(?!.*\d{6}).+ . otherwise will match a empty line.

Comment: @yudongshen yes but this is ok, a empty string is valid in this case

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you add that as an answer?

Comment: @ThomasSmyth Added, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204748/3832970)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern to match a string that has no 6 consecutive digits is

```
^(?!.*\d{6}).*
```

The [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/sDxXVU/2). If there can be line breaks inside, you need to add a DOTALL modifier that will make `.` match all chars including line break chars: `(?s)^(?!.*\d{6}).*`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches()`)
- `(?!.*\d{6})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ chars as many as possible followed with 6 consecutive digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

In Java, you may use it in the following way:

```
Boolean found = s.matches("(?s)(?!.*\\d{6}).*");
```

Note you may just try to find 6 digits with `Matcher#find` and if not found, proceed with the code excecution:

```
if (!Pattern.compile("\\d{6}").matcher(s).find()) {
    // Cool, proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace first group which match `\d{6,}` then check the result length with original length :

```
String text = "1234567 teststring";
boolean check = text.replaceFirst("\\d{6,}", "").length() == text.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex:

```
^(\D*)\d{0,5}(\D*)$
```